# CRS the same but geometry in different numeric formats

Tags: geometry, geopandas

I have two geometries with the same CRS (4326), but they have in are completely different X-Y axis formats. They should be overlapping. I am having issues with this geometry below. It says its 4326 but its the X/Y isn't in that projection.

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon
import geopandas as gpd
from descartes import PolygonPatch
```

configure the place, network type, trip times, and travel speed

```
   place = 'Stockholm, Sweden'
    network_type = 'drive'
    trip_times = [15] #in minutes
    travel_speed = 4.5 #walking speed in km/hour
    G_4326 = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type=network_type)
```

get nearest node

```
urban_intervention = ox.distance.get_nearest_node(G_4326, (59.33039855957031, 18.022981643676758))  
G_4326 = ox.project_graph(G_4326)
```

add an edge attribute for time in minutes required to traverse each edge

```
meters_per_minute = travel_speed * 1000 / 60 #km per hour to m per minute
for u, v, k, data in G_4326.edges(data=True, keys=True):
    data['time'] = data['length'] / meters_per_minute

isochrone_polys = []
for trip_time in sorted(trip_times, reverse=True):
    subgraph = nx.ego_graph(G_4326, urban_intervention, radius=trip_time, distance='time')
    node_points = [Point((data['x'], data['y'])) for node, data in subgraph.nodes(data=True)]
    bounding_poly = gpd.GeoSeries(node_points).unary_union.convex_hull
    isochrone_polys.append(bounding_poly)
```

convert to geopandas

```
treatment_radius = isochrone_polys[0]
treatment_radius_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[treatment_radius])
print(treatment_radius_gdf.crs)
print(treatment_radius_gdf)
```

result:

[image]

Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: images for code on SO are really nasty to deal with to look at your problem.  where does this geometry come from? why do you think it is epsg:4326.  To me it looks like a UTM geometry

Comment: Hi Rob, apologies -- i just tried to paint a picture of the dataset and issue (showing the XY axis'. In the first column i did 'print(df.CRS) and received 4326 for both geopandas dataframes. I got the geometry from OSMNX and converted into geopandas doing: treatment_radius_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[treatment_radius])

Comment: why do you want to believe result of df.crs?  did you load it from a shape file where CRS is defined?  it's clearly not epsg:4326,  so investigate the source and whatever documentation it has.  I can set a variable to any value,  doesn't mean it's a correct value....  I think that's happened with your CRS

Comment: Hi Rob, appreciate your advice -- i will do some digging at the source and I will be less trustworthy of python :P

Comment: update question with code (as markdown) for downloading from OSMNX and I'll investigate

Comment: I have updated and tried to shorten the code as much as possible. Apologies if its quite lengthy ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a line of code that is projecting from EPSG:4326 to a UTM CRS.  Additionally you are using very poor variable naming. you have called a variable **G_4326** when it is not after projection!

This is clearly documented: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.projection.project_graph

```
# this line changes geometry from epsg:4326 to UTM CRS
G_4326 = ox.project_graph(G_4326)
```

This makes sense given you are calculating in meters.  However that means that the generated geometry CRS is not *EPSG:4326*.  Set the CRS correctly, then you can project back to *EPSG:4326*.  Clearly this means `G_4326` is badly named, have not addressed that.

#### output

```
+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
                                            geometry
0  POLYGON ((676968.606 6569863.360, 676868.881 6...
epsg:4326
                                            geometry
0  POLYGON ((18.10176 59.23074, 18.10003 59.23086...
```

#### full code

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

place = "Stockholm, Sweden"
network_type = "drive"
trip_times = [15]  # in minutes
travel_speed = 4.5  # walking speed in km/hour
G_4326 = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type=network_type)
gdf_nodes1, gdf_edges1 = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_4326)

# this line changes geometry from epsg:4326 to UTM CRS
G_4326 = ox.project_graph(G_4326)

gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_4326)
m = gdf_edges.explore()

urban_intervention = ox.distance.get_nearest_node(
    G_4326, (59.33039855957031, 18.022981643676758)
)

meters_per_minute = travel_speed * 1000 / 60  # km per hour to m per minute
for u, v, k, data in G_4326.edges(data=True, keys=True):
    data["time"] = data["length"] / meters_per_minute

isochrone_polys = []
for trip_time in sorted(trip_times, reverse=True):
    subgraph = nx.ego_graph(
        G_4326, urban_intervention, radius=trip_time, distance="time"
    )
    node_points = [
        Point((data["x"], data["y"])) for node, data in subgraph.nodes(data=True)
    ]
    bounding_poly = gpd.GeoSeries(node_points).unary_union.convex_hull
    isochrone_polys.append(bounding_poly)
    
treatment_radius = isochrone_polys[0]
treatment_radius_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=gdf_edges.crs, geometry=[treatment_radius])
print(treatment_radius_gdf.crs)
print(treatment_radius_gdf)
print(treatment_radius_gdf.to_crs("epsg:4326").crs)
print(treatment_radius_gdf.to_crs("epsg:4326"))
treatment_radius_gdf.explore(m=m, color="red")
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked a charm.

When you say 'project it back'. Is all I needed to do this:
treatment_radius_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=gdf_edges.crs, geometry=[treatment_radius])
treatment_radius_gdf_projected = treatment_radius_gdf.to_crs("epsg:4326")

I believe i tried 1000 times the 'to.crs' so just trying to figure out why it worked this time

Comment: this is your line of code `treatment_radius_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[treatment_radius])` you have set it to the wrong CRS.  You missed fact the CRS is a UTM CRS.  so incorrect egg:4326 to epsg:436 is still wrong as initial CRS was hard coded by `crs='epsg:4326',`

Comment: Got it. So, you have to *really* hard code it in, so it knows exactly what CRS to pick. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: no, no, no - updated answer.  I've soft coded, you have hard coded.  The documentation is **very** good

Comment: Got it. I wasn't exactly sure what the UTM meant, but reading it now makes sense. Appreciate it. Also, thank you for the .explore tip! Very helpful